# ¿Un job en sql server 2008 puede ejecutar un dtsx que vive en un servidor sql server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, jobs

Recién hice una migración de paquetes dtsx de versión 3 a versión 8 de acuerdo a la compatibilidad con el servidor sql server 2016.

En particular tengo un job que se ejecuta desde un servidor sql 2008 y éste debe correr un paquete dtsx que vive en un servidor sql 2016.

¿Es posible que se pueda lograr? Ya que anteriormente había probado con otro (no lo migré) y apareció el siguiente error:

[image: Error ejecución dtsx por job]

Comment: Desconozco si se puede, te ayudo con algunas preguntas de análisis: ¿Hay alguna manera de tener un job que ejecute el paquete `dtsx` desde el `SQL 2016`? Si la hay, ¿será posible que el job del `SQL 2008` llame al job del `SQL 2016`?